# What is a manifold with cusp?

Tags: manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-topology

What I am primarily currently learning about is hyperbolic geometry and methods to find hyperbolic structures on triangulated manifolds. I see phrases such as 'cusp ends' and 'manifold with one cusp' in many, many places but I cannot seem to track down a thorough, formal definition of what it means for a manifold to have a cusp. The only use of the term cusp I am familiar with is for example for the singularity of the curve $y^2 = x^3$.

Any book references which would contain information relevant to me (in general) would be appreciated also.

Thank you.

Comment: Topologically it means a puncture. Geometrically I think there is some condition on what the metric looks like in a neighborhood of the puncture that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: What dimension are you interested in? Answer is easy in dimensions 2 (and 3, if you assume that the manifold is orientable). Also, do you want to assume finiteness of volume? If so, then the answer is again easier. Which books did you read on this subject? Did you try Thurston's book?